# pass stryng between two python scripts

Tags: python, variables, scripting, share

I need to pass a string value between two python scripts.

It's not an argument but it's a string containing a sentence (with spaces, commas and so on).

example:

one.py has a string variable "hello world, how are you today?"

and I need to pass it to two.py

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: I recommend giving a bit more information on your problem. Depending on your requirements it is useful to just import the other script. Sometimes, it's also good to write programs that read from the input so you can pipe the output to the new input.

Comment: import could be good but both scripts are very long and complicated. is there a way to import this specific string value?

Comment: can you explain me better this?
"Sometimes, it's also good to write programs that read from the input so you can pipe the output to the new input"
thanks

Comment: Forgetting about the "pass a string value" part, how were you intending to have one.py run two.py in the first place (or to have bash run both of them, or whatever)? No matter what you answer, there's an obvious solution to your problem—but it's a _different_ solution for different answers.

Comment: @jul When your python scripts are executable you can run them from the commandline / bash and make the output from one file go to the next one. Similar to: `ls -la | tail -n 5`. The same goes for python exetuables :) You should really give more information so we can find the optimal solution with you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's not an argument but it's a string containing a sentence (with spaces, commas and so on).

Why isn't that an argument?

I don't know how you were planning to run the other script, but pretty much any way of doing so allows you to pass strings with spaces, commas and so on as arguments.

If you're doing things the smart way, it works automatically:

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, path_to_script2, arg])
```

If you're doing something like `os.system` you'll have to quote the argument manually to pass it through the shell… but the easiest answer there is "don't use `os.system`, so I won't show how to do that unless you ask for it specifically.

Either way, when `script2` runs, its `sys.argv[1]` will be `arg`, with the spaces and commas and so on preserved.

---

If the string is too big, you may run into problems with maximum argv length—and, worse, they may be different problems on different platforms.

Also, if you're using Unicode, especially in Python 2.x, there can be some complexities to deal with.

But, for short-ish all-ASCII strings like `"hello world, how are you today?"`, it's all trivial.